# Neo4j graphsage model not training

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have recently started trying out Neo4j's Graphsage algorithm.

I followed the example on [this page](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/graph-sage/)

```
CREATE
  // Persons
  (  dan:Person {name: 'Dan',   age: 20, heightAndWeight: [185, 75]}),
  (annie:Person {name: 'Annie', age: 12, heightAndWeight: [124, 42]}),
  ( matt:Person {name: 'Matt',  age: 67, heightAndWeight: [170, 80]}),
  ( jeff:Person {name: 'Jeff',  age: 45, heightAndWeight: [192, 85]}),
  ( brie:Person {name: 'Brie',  age: 27, heightAndWeight: [176, 57]}),
  ( elsa:Person {name: 'Elsa',  age: 32, heightAndWeight: [158, 55]}),
  ( john:Person {name: 'John',  age: 35, heightAndWeight: [172, 76]}),

  (dan)-[:KNOWS {relWeight: 1.0}]->(annie),
  (dan)-[:KNOWS {relWeight: 1.6}]->(matt),
  (annie)-[:KNOWS {relWeight: 0.1}]->(matt),
  (annie)-[:KNOWS {relWeight: 3.0}]->(jeff),
  (annie)-[:KNOWS {relWeight: 1.2}]->(brie),
  (matt)-[:KNOWS {relWeight: 10.0}]->(brie),
  (brie)-[:KNOWS {relWeight: 1.0}]->(elsa),
  (brie)-[:KNOWS {relWeight: 2.2}]->(jeff),
  (john)-[:KNOWS {relWeight: 5.0}]->(jeff)
```

After creating the graph I ran the following **Cypher Query**:

```
CALL gds.beta.graphSage.train(
  'persons',
  {
    modelName: 'exampleTrainModel',
    featureProperties: ['age', 'heightAndWeight'],
    aggregator: 'mean',
    activationFunction: 'sigmoid',
    sampleSizes: [25, 10]
  }
) YIELD modelInfo as info
RETURN
  info.name as modelName,
  info.metrics.didConverge as didConverge,
  info.metrics.ranEpochs as ranEpochs,
  info.metrics.epochLosses as epochLosses
```

However, the `didConverge, ranEpochs, epochLosses` returned `null` values. The model itself returned the same embedding for all nodes. This shouldn't be the case as it is a working example on the site but I can't find the issue causing this to occur.

I am currently using **Neo4j** desktop on **Neo4j 4.2.5**.

Comment: Are you using GDS 1.6? And is there any step in between that you are omitting?
When I run your code I get the following error: Graph with name `persons` does not exist on database `neo4j`.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be useful for you but it can help others who land on this page. Documents were not updated. You can get all metrics by removing `YIELD` and `RETURN` statements. The following code will print all available metrics.

```
CALL gds.beta.graphSage.train(
  'persons',
  {
    modelName: 'exampleTrainModel',
    featureProperties: ['age', 'heightAndWeight'],
    aggregator: 'mean',
    activationFunction: 'sigmoid',
    sampleSizes: [25, 10]
  }
)
```